# Copy jars including all dependecies into common directory using gradle

Tags: java, gradle, build-process

I have a multi-module gradle build setup. Directory structure:

```
api/
  build.gradle
common/
  build.gradle
master/
  settings.gradle
  build.gradle
```

settings.gradle:

```
includeFlat "api", "common"
```

api build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
  compile project(':common')
}
```

common build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    // all common dependencies here
}
```

master build.gradle

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'

    task copyLibraries(type: Copy) {
        into "../lib/"
        from configurations.compile
    }
    jar {
        destinationDir = new File("../lib/")
    }
}
```

I run 'gradle clean build copyLibraries'. common.jar is 0kb. api.jar is copied correctly and has the correct code included, but some common is completely empty. All of the library jars are included correctly.

The above example is a small subset of our actual codebase. What I've noticed is any project dependency listed gets copied empty. So all of our leaf projects (not a dependency for any other project) get copied correctly, the rest do not.

Is there something I am missing, or is there another better way to move all dependencies and jars into a common directory using gradle?

Comment: Too little details. Prepare minimal working example.

Comment: updated with more details.